# Mouse events inside an editable div element

Tags: javascript, html, events, editor, mouse

I'm developing a simple html text editor and I use a div with contenteditable set to true to achieve that.

I have some buttons (bold, italic, ...) that let the user modify the text. I want to update the state of those buttons based on the state of each command, so if the cursor is inside a text that is bold then the button's image should show that bold is on.

I can achieve this with the keyup event, so on each keyup I check the state of all the commands and update the buttons.

However, I want to be able to also do that when the user clicks on part of the div. I tried the mouseup and click events for the div but they only trigger when the div gets selected not when it's content gets selected.

Is there a way to capture mouse events inside a div element so that I could update the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, just make a click event for all b or strong tags (whichever you are using) in your document. If there is bold text outside of the div, use spans with the css style `font-weight:bold;`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but what if there are many more tags than just bold and italics? should register click events for every single one?

Comment: @Milad, I see no downside to it, because no matter how many tags you have, there is always a way to attach an event with javascript. It might be a lot of code, but it will get the job done.